# Switching CSS Classes on Nested Elements via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

The goal is to switch .active classes on click. The main tabs use ".active" while the inner tabs use ".plansActive.":

[image]

What works:

- The category pane works (".active") as it should as coded in this manner:

  ```
  $('#plans a').on('click', 
    function()
    {
      $(this).closest('#plans').find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  );
  ```
- The inner tabs work as well (on load).

What does not:

- It gets buggy when category is switched from the default category (".active still works"):

[image]

- The inner tabs no longer switches to other tabs (".plansActive"), but shows their respective contents.
- This is the code for the inner tabs:

  ```
  $('.plansNumbers li a').on('click', 
    function() {
      $("a",$(this).parents("ul")).removeClass('plansActive');
      $(this).addClass('plansActive');
    }
  );
  ```

The HTML snippet looks like this:

```
<div id="plans">
    <a class="active" onclick="document.getElementById('premiumplans').innerHTML=document.getElementById('lte').innerHTML">
    <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/lteplans.png?sfvrsn=0" title="lteplans" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]8a0da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a>
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('premiumplans').innerHTML=document.getElementById('phonep').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/phoneplans.png?sfvrsn=0" title="phoneplans" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]022da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a>
</div>

<div class="plansCurrent" id="premiumplans">
    <div class="plansNumbers">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="plansActive" onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('phone1175').innerHTML"> <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-1175.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-1175" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]9a0da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('phone1675').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-1675.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-1675" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]a20da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('phone2175').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-2175.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-2175" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]aa0da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('phone3175').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-3175.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-3175" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]b20da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="plansContent" id="plansNumContent">
      <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/1175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="1175" />
    </div>

    <div id="phone1175" style="display: none;">
      <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/1175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="phone1175" />
    </div>

    <div id="phone1675" style="display: none;">
      <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/1675-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="phone1675" />
    </div>

    <div id="phone2175" style="display: none;">
      <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/2175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="phone2175" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="plansCurrent" id="lte" style="display: none;">
    <div class="plansNumbers">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="plansActive" onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('1175').innerHTML"> <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-1175.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-1175" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]9a0da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('1675').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-1675.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-1675" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]a20da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('2175').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-2175.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-2175" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]aa0da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
        <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('plansNumContent').innerHTML=document.getElementById('3175').innerHTML"><img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/nav-3175.png?sfvrsn=0" title="nav-3175" sfref="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]b20da950-71ea-6a27-ac25-ff0000b01406" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="plansContent" id="plansNumContent">
      <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/1175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="1175" />
</div>

    <div id="1175" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/1175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="1175" />
    </div>

    <div id="1675" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/1675-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="1675" />
    </div>

    <div id="2175" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/2175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="2175" />
    </div>

    <div id="3175" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="/Postpaid/images/default-source/default-album/3175-1.png?sfvrsn=0" title="3175" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Forgive me if this still looks very unclear. I am glad to clarify more if I have to.

Main Problem: **.plansActive is very buggy on switch with .active state.**

Thanks!

Comment: Y do u want to remove a class and add the same?

Comment: @Sweetz What do you mean? I edited my post now. My main problem is the inner tabs' active state classes no longer switches when the main tab switches to another ".active" class. For some reason, the switching of ".plansActive" states for the inner tabs are affected by this.

Comment: Can you maybe produce a "cleaner" example. Perhaps without the inline 'onClick` image swapping. Just the bare minimum to replicate the problem. Perhaps also a jsFidle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: This looks completely over-engineered and like a huge mess. You should consider using a simple, but reliable ready-made tab library (I like the one that comes with [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tab.js) which works on it's own if you add the missing CSS for showing/hiding the content). It is re-useable and works even if nested.

Comment: @RoToRa Yes definitely. Unfortunately, this project was just passed to me. I did not code the whole thing. Due to time constraints, I cannot simply build this from scratch and work my way there for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be here:

```
$('.plansNumbers li a').on('click', 
  function() {
    $("a",$(this).parents("ul")).removeClass('plansActive');
    $(this).addClass('plansActive');
  }
);
```

It looks like `.plansActive` should be applied to an `a` in a `li`. You are attempting to remove the class from  `a` in all `ul` instead of the immediate parent `ul`.

Try updating to:

```
$('.plansNumbers li a').on('click', 
  function() {
    //Use closest to only get immediate ul parent
    $("a",$(this).closest("ul")).removeClass('plansActive');
    $(this).addClass('plansActive');
  }
);
```

**Update**

As you are adding and removing elements you are going to break the jquery event handlers. If you want to keep going with adding and removing elements look closer at [jquery's on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event listeners to dynamically added elements. You need to "anchor" the on to an element that won't be added like (note I have't tested this):

```
$('.plansNumbers').on('click', 'li a' 
  function() {
    $("a",$(this).parents("ul")).removeClass('plansActive');
    $(this).addClass('plansActive');
  }
);
```

Personally I would not add be adding and removing, just hiding and showing. Something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="plnMenu">
    <a href="#plnPremium">Premium</a>
    <a href="#plnLTE">LTE</a>
</div>
<div id="plnDisplay">
    <ul class="plans">
        <li id="plnPremium" class="active">
            <ul>
                <li id="pln1175" >
                    <h3>1175</h3>
                    <div>1175 Premium Content</div>
                </li>
                <li id="pln1675" class="active">
                    <h3>1675</h3>
                    <div>1675 Premium Content</div>
                </li>
                <li id="pln2175">
                    <h3>2175</h3>
                    <div>2175 Premium Content</div>
                </li>
                <li id="pln2675">
                    <h3>2675</h3>
                    <div>2675 Premium Content</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="plnLTE"> 
             <ul>
                <li class="pln1175 active" >
                    <h3>1175</h3>
                    <div>1175 Content</div>
                </li>
                <li class="pln1675">
                    <h3>1675</h3>
                    <div>1675 Content</div>
                </li>
                <li class="pln2175">
                    <h3>2175</h3>
                    <div>2175 Content</div>
                </li>
                <li class="pln2675">
                    <h3>2675</h3>
                    <div>2675 Content</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS** with some very rough styling

```
#plnMenu
{
    width:70px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    z-index:0;
}

#plnMenu>a
{
    display:block;
    width:70px;
    padding: 10px 3px;
}

#plnMenu>a.active
{
    font-weight:bold;
}

#plnDisplay
{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;

}
#plnDisplay .plans {padding:5px;}


#plnDisplay .plans>li
{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}

#plnDisplay .plans>li.active
{
    display:block;
}

#plnDisplay .plans>li>ul>li
{
    float:left;
    width:75px;
}

#plnDisplay .plans>li>ul>li>h3
{
    background-color:#fee;
    position:relative;
    font-size:24px;
    padding:6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:0;
}

#plnDisplay .plans>li>ul>li>div
{
    display:none;
    background-color:#eef;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:476px;
    padding:6px;
    height:236px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10;
}

#plnDisplay .plans>li>ul>li.active>h3
{
    background-color:#eef;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:none;
    z-index:100;
}

#plnDisplay .plans>li>ul>li.active>div
{
    display:block;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$("#plnMenu>a").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#plnMenu>a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    //console.log(target);
    //console.log($("#plnDisplay .plans>li"));
    $("#plnDisplay .plans>li").removeClass("active");
    console.log($(target));
    $(target).addClass("active");
    return false;
});

$("#plnDisplay .plans>li>ul>li>h3").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/13az4uLy/4/)

Comment: How come it works on page load? The .plansActive class works on every inner tab as expected when the main tabs (.active) are not clicked. Once they do, the inner tabs' .plansActive stays on the first child element.

Anyway, what do you suggest would work instead?

Comment: I missed the context in the selector. I've updated, I think the problem is you are targeting not just the immediate parent `ul` but all ancestor `ul` as well with `parents`

Comment: Hi Jon, your code didn't change anything. It still leaves the ".plansActive" state on the first child of the element once I switch the main tabs on click. For some reason the switching of the main tabs affects the assigning of classes on the inner tabs.

Comment: I've also just noticed you're dynamically replacing content which also could be part of your issue. Instead of changing `innerHTML` are you havle to hide/show the approptrate content instead?

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll figure out the rest myself using these suggestions. Thanks, Jon!